# I want to float 3rd child menu to left

Tags: css, navigation, css-transitions, navigationbar

how to float third child menu to left?
i want to float 3rd child menu to left like the main menu "item1"

**html**

```
   <nav id="nav">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
     <ul class"right-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li> 
    </ul>       
    </li> 
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add your fiddle link correctly!

Comment: If you add fiddle, You also need to add code

Comment: I guess [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) is what you need.

Comment: Next time, always provide code if you want to show us jsFiddle

Comment: I have troubling to post css code :( its says   it looks like your post is mostly code please add more details.

Comment: Anyway whatever here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hsn0/rPUcY/

Comment: how do i add css code its not posting :( its says 

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the word `float` correctly. And the tag `css-transitions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the 3rd child in CSS using the :nth-child syntax.

CSS

```
#nav ul li ul li:nth-child(3)
```

However if you want something that will be supported in all browsers I tend to use the adjacent sibling selector or "+".

In your example the css would be:

```
#nav ul li ul li + li + li {
  float:left;
}
```

Although i would recommend using some classes so that you can reduce the huge number of selectors requires to do this.

Comment: Did you see my fiddle here?? please take a look here  http://www.jsfiddle.net/hsn0/rPUcY and give me the right solution. i cant understand your this technique.

Comment: its not working what u give example please explain it with details. with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hsn0/rPUcY/